# Creating new Datatables for every new "group" in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design

I have a little problem with my database, but I think it's more of a thinking problem than a programming problem. So I am programming a live football manager with users, that can enter a league, a little bit like FMO, but with real players. There is a transfer market, where the users can buy players and set their teams with it. I have made some datatables like footballplayer, user, and football team, where all real football players and real football teams are set. The problem is that every league created must have an own set of football players and football teams, so when a user of league1 builds his own team with football player a,b and c, this football players should not be purchasable for someone who is in league1. But when you are in league2, nothing of league1 affects your league, so football player a,b and c are available in league2. I hope it was not too confusing for you guys and I am thankful for every advise you give.

Comment: why is that a problem? If the player is purchased, he becomes related to the team which in turn is related to the league. Easy to find out which players are available / not available in any given league.

Comment: Just add the leagueId to your players, users, teams etc.

Comment: @FabianH. not quite. It'll need to be a many-many relationship, otherwise each player can only be in one league. Teams probably have a one-many relationship to the league (or perhaps, if users _claim_ real teams (instead of creating custom ones), then they also have a many-many, if they are included in any given created league, it's hard to tell from the description). Users don't have a direct relationship to the league, just via the teams they create.

Comment: I am quite new to working with databases and I dont know how to realize it. Can I create like a new Instance of football players for every league, or how exactly can it be solved?

Comment: No, you need an intermediate table which maps players to teams, such that a player can be linked to multiple teams (and of course a team can have many players). Research many-to-many relationships.

Comment: @ADyson ok I will look it up thanks.
I have linked player with teams through foreign keys. But as you said, my description was a little bit vague. So users create custom teams. The datatable football team is more like a source of information. So every player has a relationship to one football team. This football team table just has the name of the real team of the player, how much goals this team has, which position in the real league they have.

Comment: The user can create a custom team with players from different "real teams". For example user1 buys cristiano ronaldo who's team is real madrid and messi who's team is barcelona

Comment: Ok I see, so it's similar to a Fantasy Football type of setup. In that case yeah your players can have a single Real Team which they are associated to, but then they need a many-to-many relationship to Custom Team, so that the player can appear in multiple leagues. Then each Custom Team is associated with both a single User, and a single League. With that structure you can easily find out which players are purchased / available for any particular league by looking at the associations between players and custom teams (restricted by the team's link to its league)

Comment: @ADyson Allright, thanks for the tip, I will try it out :)